# Cypher: Ordering Nodes on Same Level by Property on Relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am new to `Neo4j` and currently playing with this tree structure:

[image]

The numbers in the yellow boxes are a property named `order` on the relationship `CHILD_OF`.

**My goal was**

a) to manage the sorting order of nodes at the same level through this property rather than through directed relationships (like e.g. `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `IS_NEXT_SIBLING`, etc.).

b) being able to use plain integers instead of complete paths for the `order` property (i.e. not maintaining sth. like `0001.0001.0002`).

I can't however find the right hint on how or if it is possible to recursively query the graph so that it keeps returning the nodes `depth-first` but for the sorting at each level consider the `order` property on the relationship.

I expect that if it is possible it might include matching the complete path iterating over it with the collection utilities of `Cypher`, but I am not even close enough to post some good starting point.

**Question**

What I'd expect from answers to this question is not necessarily a solution, but a hint on whether this is a bad approach that would perform badly anyways. In terms of `Cypher` I am interested if there is a practical solution to this.

I have a general idea on how I would tackle it as a Neo4j server plugin with the Java traversal or core api (which doesn't mean that it would perform well, but that's another topic), so this question really targets the design and `Cypher` aspect.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
match path = (n:Root {id:9})-[:CHILD_OF*]->(m)
WITH path, extract(r in rels(path) | r.order) as orders
ORDER BY orders
```

if it complains about sorting arrays then computing a number where each digit (or two digits) are your order and order by that number

```
match path = (n:Root {id:9})-[:CHILD_OF*]->(m)
WITH path, reduce(a=1, r in rels(path) | a*10+r.order) as orders
ORDER BY orders
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael. On a quick try the first query yields a syntax error while the second one seems to work. I can't test it in detail now but will revisit during the week and then approve the answer or get back with a comment .

Comment: fixed the first query

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply. You were right about the first query complaining about comparing multiple depths (can't compare left to right, e.g. `[1, 1]` to `[1]`). The second one works, but unless I read it wrong does not seem to return the results `depth-first` but rather `breadth-first`, e.g. `[11], [12], [111], [112], ..., [1112]`.